# Postgres table : Find duplicates in two columns, regardless of order

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, aggregate-functions

i have a PostgreSQL table describing lines between two points. It contains two columns, A and B, integers representing the id of a point (described in another table).

But each line is duplicated in the table, as the line going from A to B is the same that the line going from B to A.

I'd like to remove the duplicates, but i can't find an aggregate function working on two columns, to regroup AB and BA lines then to remove one.

Thanks :)

Comment: There are at least two possible ways I can envisage the duplication in this case.  ***`1).`*** that the `Lines` table contains a record that points to `point_id(1), point_id(2)` and also a record that points to `point_id(2), point_id(1)`.  ***`2.`*** That the two lines all have different point_id values, but that when you look in the `point` table, different point_ids can have the same co-ordinates.  Could you give examples to clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The duplicates are in point_ids, not in coordinates, so it's the first case of your question. Moreover, alls the lines are duplicated, for each AB line there is a BA line, it's a result of the table creation aglorithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Identifying the duplicates:

```
select least(a,b), greatest(a,b), count(*)
from the_table
group by least(a,b), greatest(a,b)
having count(*) > 1
```

I think you should be able to delete one of the pairs using:

```
delete from the_table
where (least(a,b), greatest(a,b)) in (
                select least(a,b), greatest(a,b)
                from the_table
                group by least(a,b), greatest(a,b)
                having count(*) > 1);
```

(Not tested!)

Comment: Hmmm... it now seems to me this will delete more than just the duplicate records

Comment: @LaurentJégou - This will delete every record for any line that has duplicates; if a line exists as `a,b` AND `b,a`, both records will be deleted. It needs only to have `WHERE (a,b) IN (` then it will only delete instances of the line where `a<b`. This then assumes that any line with a duplicate exists as both `a,b` and `b,a`, and also assumes that no line will have multiple `a,b` entries *(so that deleting all of the `b,a` entries will be sufficient)*.  In which case, it becomes functionally very similar to my answer, but with a little extra complexity ;)

Comment: I agree with Dems comment, i used the "where (a, b) in" version, and it deleted only duplicates.

Comment: @LaurentJégou - In which case I think this is slightly over complex as it exhibits the same behaviour (and assumptions) as my simpler answer. I would expect, though I have not tested, that this answer would also be slower (more cpu, more reads) than the simpler answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've left a comment, but I'm going to assume for now that the only difference between two *duplicate* records is that they have the same point_id values, but in reverse order.

In which case, it is actually quite simple to do...

```
DELETE
  line
WHERE
  point_id_a > point_id_b
  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM line AS lookup
               WHERE lookup.point_id_a = line.point_id_b
                 AND lookup.point_id_b = line.point_id_a
             )
```

Comment: +1 This works assuming that the only duplicates have a,b swapped.  It won't work if there are multiple rows with the same a,b

Comment: @Andomar - Correct, that's why I stated such an assumption :) But, interestingly, the accepted answer seems to be both incorrect (deletes all occurances, not just the duplicates) and even when corrected will make virtually the same assumption as my answer. *(See my comment on the answer.)*